# Entity Framework Code First: MultiLevel TPC Inheritance With Relationships in the Middle Level

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am using TPC inheritance to map a complex object model to an existing database. I am running into an issue when I create a relationship in the middle level of my inheritance structure.

```
public class ParentClass
{
}

public class MiddleClass : ParentClass
{
    public Int64 RelationshipId;
    public Relationship Relationship;
}

public class ChildClass1 : MiddleClass
{
}

public class ChildClass2: MiddleClass
{
}

public class Relationship
{
    public string RelationshipInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ParentClass> Parents
    public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClass1>.Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClass2>.Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MiddleClass>.HasRequired(mc => mc.Relationship).WithMany().HasForeignKey(mc => mc.RelationshipId);
    }
}
```

My model will work until I add the `modelBuilder.Entity<MiddleClass>.HasRequired(mc => mc.Relationship).WithMany().HasForeignKey(mc => mc.RelationshipId);` line. Do I have to map this relationship to every child?

The error I receive is *'The type "MiddleClass" cannot be mapped as defined because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another form of inheritance.'*

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer (sort of) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781707/entity-framework-code-first-tpc-inheritance-self-referensing-child-class). The basic answer is that since any of the inherited classes are not represented as tables in the database, you cannot create relationships on those tables.

Even attempting to map the inherited property through the parent class like so will not work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClass>()
            .HasRequired(cc => cc.Relationship).WithMany().HasForeignKey(cc => cc.RelationshipId);
```

It understands that the Relationship object is still part of the MiddleClass "table" and tries to map it there. It seems the only action is to have all relationship objects in the Child Classes.

```
public class ParentClass
{
}

public class MiddleClass : ParentClass
{
    public Int64 RelationshipId;
    public Relationship Relationship;
}

public class ChildClass1 : MiddleClass
{
    public Int64 RelationshipId;
    public Relationship Relationship;
}

public class ChildClass2: MiddleClass
{
    public Int64 RelationshipId;
    public Relationship Relationship;
}

public class Relationship
{
    public string RelationshipInfo { get; set; }
}
```

This isn't the best solution, but you can probably do your mapping through an inherited structure of EntityConfigurations.